# mysql_real_escape_string causes problems?

Tags: php, mysql, sha1

Okay. So I made a form. If I put in `mysql_real_escape_string` on my variable `$usrname` (yes its spelled right) that was retrieved from the form, it returns my other variable, `$verify` as `false`. Take a look:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php  

session_start();

include("mainmenu.php");  

$usrname = $_POST['usrname']; 
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Y0U_C@NT_H@NDLE_THE_TRUTH!");
 if(!$con){
  die("Unable to establish connection with host. We apologize for any inconvienience.");
}

mysql_select_db("users", $con) or die("Can't connect to database.");

$select = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE usrname = '$usrname' and
password = '$password'";
$query = mysql_query($select);
$verify = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($verify==1){
    $_SESSION["valid_user"] = $usrname;
    header("location:index.php");
}
else{
     echo "Wrong username or password. Please check that CAPS LOCK is off.";
     echo "<br/>";
     echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Back to login</a>";
} 

mysql_close($con);

?> 
</body>
```

If I put the `mysql_real_escape_string` in either my registration form or login form, it returns `$verify` as `false`. What's wrong?

Comment: Because you did something wrong. Unfortunately, you did not see fit to show us the code that you actually executed, so it's impossible to say what that might be.

Comment: I SEE YOU HAVE YOUR CRUISE CONTROL FOR COOL TURNED ON.

Comment: is the database column name usrname as well instead of username ?

Comment: dang, somebody beat me to fixing the title

Comment: @Ken: IN FUTURE, PLEASE DON'T SHOUT!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: ... and yet you did see fit to show us your root MySQL password? Nobody wants to see that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure "Magic Quotes" is off in the PHP settings. How to disable it is explained [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Comment: If your host doesn't allow you to disable it immediately, strip the magic quotes as the first thing in your scripts.

Comment: they are disabled... still nothing

Comment: If your host doesn't allow you to disable it immediately, follow the instructions on the page that I linked :) Example #2 explains how to disable it at runtime.