# Most bizarre PHP/ MySQL bug

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search page that takes what you searched for (via POST) and then inserts it in a table. I had it email the query to me so I could see what was going on:

My PHP that gets the variable:

```
$searched = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searched']);
```

The query that uses it (emailed to me):

```
INSERT INTO conversations (viID, moID, viTyping, moTyping, priority, status, open, mOpen, lastMsgID, searched) VALUES (435, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, "
```

Here is the code that assembles the query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO conversations (viID, moID, viTyping, moTyping, priority, status, open, mOpen, lastMsgID, searched) VALUES ($userID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, \"$searched\")";
```

Whenever the page runs from IE, this inserts the record in the DB just fine. Any other brower leaves out the "question8" part (it still inserts a record), even though the query is EXACTLY THE SAME! I can cut and paste the query in phpMyAdmin and it runs just fine.

Why would this only work in IE? Are the other browsers inserting some special characters I can't see in there? I'm lost!

Comment: can we see the code that assembles the query?

Comment: The browser should be irrelevant (Unless it relates to the $_POST variable) as it's all server side - Could you post the code as it appears in your PHP file, please?

Comment: Dump the contents of `$_POST` and see what's inside. Make sure you escape your query too.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure "Magic Quotes" is off in the PHP settings. How to disable it is explained [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

(Exact same answer from me copy/pasted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675737/mysql-real-escape-string-causes-problems/4675747#4675747)).

Answer (score 0):

Probably something wrong or browser specific in your HTML or javascript used on the search page.

Answer (score 0):

Could you let me know if this works (`$db_con` refers to your MySQL connection resource);

```
$searched = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['searched'], $db_con);

$query = "INSERT INTO conversations (viID, moID, viTyping, moTyping, priority, status, open, mOpen, lastMsgID, searched) VALUES ('".$userID."', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, '".$searched."')";
```

Comment: Could you edit your post to include all of the relevant code, please - including declaration of $userID? Thanks :)